# accessing primary account and call it in your own UI

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to access the account that is used primary for android.
From that account i want to send email using my own layout.

Like in this iPhone activity we send reciver address:

[image]

Android ACTION SEND  intent doesn't support to display the attach image.

Answer (score 1):

intent ACTION SEND has Intent.EXTRA_STREAM as parameter, which contains the URI of the file to be uploaded.

You can read the stream and display the image as you need in your layout.